# algorithm: get next year date work shift type according week number

Tags: algorithm, datetime, week-number

I work in 3 shifts, each week different one. The order is morning shift (`m`), night one (`n`) and afternoon one (`a`). The order i fixed, i.e. it never changes, even if one won't work that week.

I created a function to get ISO week number. When I throw it a date, it returns week number.

This week (no. 48), for example, I work morning, therefore `48 % 3 = 0 → m = 0; n = 1; a = 2`.
I saved this into array `shifts = ["m", "n", "a"]`.

This is the easy part. But as the end of the year comes, I need to solve a problem. As 52 (the total number of weeks in 2017) is not divisible by 3 and there are different number of weeks in different years, modulo 0 (which for year 2017 means `m`), means something else in different years.

So, the actual question is what would be the fastest and simplest algorithm (rather fastest than simplest), doesn't need to be human-readable, with explanation (if necessary) why/how does it do what it does.

I thought of one (which is neither fast nor simple): to the known week no. & shift type combo add the number of weeks following that week until the end of the year, and recalculate the array shifts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use ISO week numbers ?
Let's say that your weeks start on some specific day (monday, sunday, you decide). You decide of a starting date `d0`, also a week start, for shift `0`. Then for any date `d` your shift is:

```
shift = floor(nbdays(d - d0) / 7) mod 3
```

Problems may arise if your system work in different locales where the starting day for a week is not the same. In that case you should have a specific `d0` for each locale. If your `shift` is the same worldwide you have no problem.

Comment: (1) I thought of ISO week numbers because I live in a country where they are used. True that I don’t need them, but I’ve never thought about it that way. :) … (2) It’s only for my personal usage, therefore there won’t be any troubles with diffrent locales. :) … (3) What is `nbdays`?

Comment: @tukusejssirs Re-reading myself my question may look passive-aggressive. That was not the intent. I was wondering if you have specific requirements about week numbers that would invalidate my algorithm. Apparently not :)

Comment: I was not offended by any means, so don’t worry. :) … I think I will change it to the solution of your answer. … I just asked your to tell me what is that nbdays. Thanks.

Comment: `nbdays` is computing the number of days between the two dates. In c# you would write: `d.Substract(d0).TotalDays`